# How can I process OPUS format with Librosa?

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I am trying to generate spectrograms by using Librosa. When I was working with the .wav format file it was working fine. But I changed the format to OPUS audio codec and tried to run the same file, it give me below error.

```
X, sample_rate = librosa.load('TESS emotion datasets opus/OAF_Fear/OAF_beg_fear.opus', res_type='kaiser_fast', duration = 2.5, sr = 22050*2, offset = 0.5)
```

Error generated:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    145     try:
--> 146         with sf.SoundFile(path) as sf_desc:
    147             sr_native = sf_desc.samplerate

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, samplerate, channels, subtype, endian, format, closefd)
    628                                          format, subtype, endian)
--> 629         self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
    630         if set(mode).issuperset('r+') and self.seekable():

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py in _open(self, file, mode_int, closefd)
   1183         _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
-> 1184                      "Error opening {0!r}: ".format(self.name))
   1185         if mode_int == _snd.SFM_WRITE:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py in _error_check(err, prefix)
   1356         err_str = _snd.sf_error_number(err)
-> 1357         raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
   1358 

RuntimeError: Error opening 'TESS emotion datasets opus/OAF_Fear/OAF_beg_fear.opus': File contains data in an unimplemented format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NoBackendError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-1372f02f676e> in <module>()
----> 1 X, sample_rate = librosa.load('TESS emotion datasets opus/OAF_Fear/OAF_beg_fear.opus', res_type='kaiser_fast', duration = 2.5, sr = 22050*2, offset = 0.5)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    161         if isinstance(path, (str, pathlib.PurePath)):
    162             warnings.warn("PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.")
--> 163             y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
    164         else:
    165             raise (exc)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py in __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
    185 
    186     y = []
--> 187     with audioread.audio_open(path) as input_file:
    188         sr_native = input_file.samplerate
    189         n_channels = input_file.channels

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/audioread/__init__.py in audio_open(path, backends)
    114 
    115     # All backends failed!
--> 116     raise NoBackendError()

NoBackendError:
```

I tried to install  `ffmpeg` and `gstreamer` as suggested by some previous answers and [github page of Librosa](https://github.com/librosa/tutorial). But it didn't solve the problem.

On the contrary, this audio format works well when I run the same code in Google Colab.

What can be the reason of this error? How to solve it?